# User Settings for all users

Tags: c#

I know there has to be a way to have Application/User settings that are read/write and be the same for all users. I write code for automated laser marking machines that are installed in factories. I want the code to be as simple as

```
        private void _btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.IOCOM = comboIOCOM.Text;
        Settings.Default.TLoc = tbTLoc.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

but I don't want the .config file to be saved in each user's folder. I want the same settings to be used by all users.

things to keep in mind when answering is that the user that will be logged in will have admin rights to the c:\ and all folders

Also, I am using VS 2010.

Comment: Couldn't you just cut out the fact that it's a button and hard code the settings you want into the code? That way they couldn't change anything no matter who runs the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to use the EF and SQLite to store all the settings for my applications. This way I can load from the DB to a Model and store the DB file to any location I wish. Also I gain the structure and organisation of SQL and can skip all the serialization of an XML file. In addition, the DB file is not plain text and I can limit an unauthorized user from changing setting by using notepad.

Answer (score 2):

Not automatically like the `user.config` or the `app.config`. But the way to do it is use `Environment.GetFolderPath(` to find the `CommonApplicationData` folder.

```
//Finding the file
var commonPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var programPath = Path.Combine(commonPath, "Your Programs Name");
var settingFile = Path.Combine(programPath, "settings.xml");



//Saving settings
Directory.CreateDirectory(programPath);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourCustomSettingsType));
using(var fs = File.Open(settingFile, FileMode.Create))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fs, yourCustomSettings);
}


//loading settings
try
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourCustomSettingsType));
    using(var fs = File.Open(settingFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        yourCustomSettings = (YourCustomSettingsType)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
catch
{
    //If it fails to load just use the default settings (set in the constructor)
    yourCustomSettings = new YourCustomSettingsType();

    //Save the settings out so it won't fail next time.
    SaveSettings(yourCustomSettings);
}
```

You would use your custom settings class just like you would use the normal settings class.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what the xml file would look like and how I would use the values in the xml in my code?

Comment: Would I still use the settings like this spIO.PortName = Settings.Default.IOCOM; ?

Comment: @bkjames for your first question, it would look a lot like user.config or app.config as this is exactly what that does. For the default you can do it too but like I said it is not automatic so you will need to create and load the settings yourself in to the `Default` property. Look at `Settings.Designer.cs` in one of your projects that already has user or app settings to see how it handles the property, it will be up to you to re-create the code inside `ApplicationSettingsBase`. The code I gave you is not a full solution by far, but intended as to give you a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @bkjames One gotcha my above code does not handle. The `Directory.CreateDirectory(programPath);` step may create a new folder that only the user who created the directory can read. If that happens you will need to change permissions on that folder when you create it to allow all users to access the folder. If you need help doing that feel free to ask a new question about changing permissions on folders.

Comment: That won't be a problem. I will create the folder before we ship the machine.